# Fluked code: why does it work?

Tags: javascript

The following javascript code does exactly what I want it to do:

```
function setDistances() {
var distances = [];
    //get values of ten numeric HTML fields
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var thiswide = document.getElementById("dist"+i).value;
      //This value is a string, despite coming from a numeric field.
   if (thiswide = Number(thiswide)){      //excluding blanks
      distances.push(thiswide);        //putting value in an array
 }} }
```

It only works because I made a mistake. Had I written `if (thiswide == Number(thiswide))` then it would fail to exclude the blanks because javascript treats "" as equal to 0, as I found out after noticing the error.

So how does `if (thiswide = Number(thiswide))` exclude the blanks?

Comment: if thiswide is blank, then `Number(thiswide)` is 0, the result is assigned to thiswide, and is falsey

Comment: 'this' is a keyword and has particular properties.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this or http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: @jeff, read the actual code :p if it were `this wide` then there would be a syntax error and the javscript wouldn't run at all

Comment: @JaromandaX I did thiswide and this wide are not the same thing

Comment: oh ... damn, I **didn't** read the actual code!!! I stopped reading at the if condition, not the block of code after it

Comment: `if (thiswide = Number(thiswide))` is complete different in syntax and meaning than `if (thiswide == Number(this wide))` .. which error is the mistake that worked?

Comment: This code does not even compile/interpreted at all. I strongly doubt that you are executing a different file that what you actually see

Comment: Corrected now. The actual code only ever said "thiswide".  The "this wide" in my question was an autocorrect error, for which I apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (thiswide == Number(thiswide))` compares `thiswide` to the result of `Number(thiswide)`. In the case of '': `Number('')` results to 0 and `0 == ''` because the loose equals (`==`) allows type conversion. ( `0 === ''` would return false)

With `if (thiswide = Number(thiswide))` , `Number(thiswide)` is calculated, its result assigned to the variable `thiswide` and then that variable (a number) is boolified. For a numeric value, 0 is false (so is `NaN`), all other values true. So everything that is parsed to 0, is not added. Since Number('') == 0 , the if evaluates to false.

In steps: Number('') results in 0, thiswide gets the value 0, the remaining evaluation is `if(0)` which is interpreted as `if(false)`